# How to sort an Observable with Observable parameters ? rxjs

Tags: sorting, angular, rxjs

I am trying to modify and then sort a list. I am completely noob at this :(

I was able to do it with 'combineLatest' but the problem is that I have always to modify array with the function below 'groupByDateAndTournament'.
My outcome:

1. create observable of the list and sorting parameters (favoriteTournaments, teamRanks)
2. modify list with 'groupByAndTournament' only if observable list has changed
3. sort by favorite only if obsevable favoriteTournament has changed
4. sort by ranks only if observable teamRank has changed

   ```
       this.subscription =  
       this.matchesService.getUpcoming()
       .merge(
       this.favoriteService.getFavoriteTournaments().flatMap((data) => {
           return {'favoriteTournaments': data}
       }),
       this.teamsService.getTeamRanking().flatMap((data) => {
           return {'teamRanks': data}
       })

   ).scan((acc, curr) => {
       let upcomingMatches;
       if (curr.upcoming) {
           upcomingMatches = this.groupByDateAndTournament(curr);
       }
       if (curr.favoriteTournaments) {
           upcomingMatches = this.sortByFavorite(curr)
       }

       if (curr.teamRanks) {
           upcomingMatches = this.sortByRank(curr);
       }
       return upcomingMatches;

   })
       .subscribe()
   ```

Comment: Why you don't use just plain old `Array.sort(...)`? It's hard to understand what is this code supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

So I managed it with combineLatest

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        this.matchesService.getUpcoming().map((data)=> this.upcomingService.combineUpcomings(data)),
        this.favoriteService.getFavoriteTournaments(),
        this.teamsService.getTeamRanking(),
        (matches, favoriteTournaments, teamRanks) => this.upcomingService.prepareUpcomingMatches(matches, favoriteTournaments, teamRanks)
    ).subscribe((data)=>
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.upcomingMatches = data;
            this.loading = false;
        })
    );
```

It still has issues.`PrepareUpcomingMatches`function is reruning when any of the observables is changed.